# How to input a footnote in a table environment

Tags: tables, footnotes

How do I put a footnote number in a table and the note at the bottom of the same page? Using the `\footnote{}` command put a footnote number in the table where I wanted it, but no footnote on that page.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-footintab.html

Comment: Generally you do not add footnotes to tables. Instead you add table notes, usually added directly below the table. See eg the threeparttablex package

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is dividing `\footnote{}` into 2 parts: putting `\footnotemark` inside a table and `\footnotetext{}` outside it.